# Dynamic update Dash Datatable from df

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I'm creating an auto-update Dash datatable. The data is obtained from a SQL Server Query, passed to a Dataframe and displayed in the datatable:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.MINTY, 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css'])

sql_query = ('''SELECT * FROM HOSVITAL.dbo.Censo_Diario
                ORDER BY Dias_Estancia DESC''')

server = '#srv' 
database = '#db' 
username = '#usr' 
password = '#pwd' 
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

df = pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn)
     
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() 
                if x.dtype == "object" else x)  # Trim whitespaces
```

After that, i'm defining a function for connect to my DB and another function for get and clean the data and return it as a dict:

```
def connectSQLServer(conn):
    connSQLServer = conn
    return connSQLServer

def getData():
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for idx in range(10):
        data  = pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn)
        df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() 
                if x.dtype == "object" else x)
        df2 = df2.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        df2 = df2.drop_duplicates().sort_index()
    return df2.to_dict('records')
```

I´m giving custom name to the df columns:

```
tblcols=[{'name': 'Pabellon', 'id': 'Pabellon'},
         {'name': 'Cama', 'id': 'Cama'},
         {'name': 'Cedula', 'id': 'Cedula'}, 
         {'name': 'Tipo', 'id': 'Tipo'}, 
         {'name': 'EPS', 'id': 'EPS'}, 
         {'name': 'Nivel', 'id': 'Nivel'}, 
         {'name': 'Ingreso', 'id': 'Ingreso'}, 
         {'name': 'Nombre', 'id': 'Nombre'},
         {'name': 'Edad', 'id': 'Edad'},
         {'name': 'Cod', 'id': 'Cod'},
         {'name': 'Diagnostico', 'id': 'Diagnostico'},
         {'name': 'Fecha Ingreso', 'id': 'Fecha_Ingreso'}, 
         {'name': 'Dias Estancia', 'id': 'Dias_Estancia'}
         ]
```

Create my layout adding a Dcc.interval for update the data every 5 seconds:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
      html.H4('CN Dashboard'),
      dcc.Interval('graph-update', interval = 5000, n_intervals = 0),
      dbc.Container([
          dash_table.DataTable(
              sort_action='native',
              id = 'table',
              css=[{
                    'selector': '.dash-cell div.dash-cell-value',
                    'rule': 'display: inline; white-space: inherit; overflow: inherit; text-overflow: inherit;'
                }],
              data = getData(),
              columns=tblcols,]
)
```

Finally, I create this callback for update the table:

```
@app.callback(

        dash.dependencies.Output('table','data'),
        [dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def updateTable(n):
     return getData()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port = 8070)
    app.title = 'Tablero CN' # appears in browser title bar
```

So, this App is displaying the data and it´s updating as expected, but the problem is that all rows are being duplicated in the Output.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a good idea to update the question completely after getting the answer and accepting it and again removing its acceptance?

Comment: In this scenario, the answer becomes so irrelevant for the updated question. It was the correct answer though

Answer (score 0):

1. Error(Invalid prop for this component) - basically it is stating that **dash_bootstrap_components.Table** does not support **data** argument where you are trying to push update using callback. **dash table** has this feature. seems you imported it in code but didn't use. As far as I know it can't be solved with **dbc**. you can use dash_table if you really want this callback.
2. Query Re-usability - if both queries are same why not define query as variable in top as you did with **conn** and pass it as argument.

example:

```
query =  '''select * from table'''
```